# Splunk Enterprise pie-chart with count from different search criteria

Tags: pie-chart, splunk

I'm trying to create a pie chart where i'v 2 search result sets from different condition and different source. But i'm not able to join the result set into one pie chart.

```
index=A sourcetype=B host=C | rex "pattern1" | chart count(field1) AS result1
index=A sourcetype=B host=C | rex "pattern2" | chart count(field2) AS result2
index=A sourcetype=B host=D | rex "pattern3" | chart count(field3) AS result3;
```

I'm able to get data for pattern1 and pattern2 as they have same index/sourcetype/host but cant join data from 3rd one.

```
PieChart should represent resullt1, result2, others(resul3 - result1 - result2) out of result3
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first get all of the results into the same result set before pulling them together into the chart. How easy this will be will depend on the regex or whether you can use normal eval conditions to split the categories.

```
index=A sourcetype=B host IN (C OR D)
| eval result = if(host = "C" AND _raw LIKE "%pattern1%", "result1",
  host = "C" AND _raw LIKE "%pattern2%", "result2",
  host = "D" AND _raw LIKE "%pattern3%", "other",
  true(), "NA"
)
| where result != "NA"
| eval field = coalesce(field1, field2, field3)
| chart count(field) by result
```

Failing that, you can use `|append` to join your existing searches into the same result set with a common field, e.g. `result` and then do your `|chart count by result`. Something like the below.

```
index=A sourcetype=B host=C | rex "pattern1" | stats count(field1) AS result | eval type="type1"
|append [index=A sourcetype=B host=C | rex "pattern2" | stats count(field2) AS result | eval type = "type2"]
|append [index=A sourcetype=B host=D | rex "pattern3" | stats count(field3) AS result | eval type="other"]
| table type result
```